# How to copy elements into a div after an on click action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Using JavaScript and JQuery and underscore

Currently I have the following

```
<div id="select"></div>
```

which is populated by the following code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.go img').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('.go').on('click', 'img', function (e) {
        $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#select');
```

So at the moment only the img is taken and placed inside #select, but I would also like for it to include item.A item.C and item.C

But I'm not sure how to change the `$(document).ready(function () {` code block to achieve this?

I thought I might need to give the div an id and reference that?

I've been able to take the whole lot by concatenating the code block, but thats not how I want it to work, I'd like each element seperate so that I can target it with CSS.

---

```
_.each(Badges, function (item) {
    var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
    wrapper.append('<img class="images BadgeImgOutline responsive-image" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />');
    wrapper.append('<div>' + item.A + '</div>');
    wrapper.append('<div>' + item.B + '</div>');
    wrapper.append('<div>' + item.C + '</div>');
    $('#container').append(wrapper);
});
```

Comment: Cheers, if you make it the answer I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuerys ".parent()" method to get the parent of the img tag - in this case your wrapper div and add this to your select.

The code could look like so:

```
$(this).width(100).height(100);
$(this).parent().appendTo('#select');
```

for shrinking the image and appending the whole wrapper including img and items to your select.

Hope this helps